# Не создается лог файл вне среды разработки с помощью библиотеки log4j

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

Доброго времени суток!

Среда разработки IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4.

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**log4j2.properties**

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.basePath = ./

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${basePath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = app
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
```

Jar файл собираю с помощью плагина:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Когда запускаю приложение в среде разработки, то все отлично работает. Однако при запуске собранного JAR файла файл с логами не создается. Я уже голову сломал, никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Подскажите, если кто-то с таким сталкивался.

Comment: `properties` куда складываете?

Comment: в каталоге resources лежит

Comment: откройте созданный jar-файл zip-ом и посмотрите есть ли в корне архива `log4j.properties`

Comment: И еще, вы уверенны, что смотрите в правильное место? При запуске из IDE логи будут в `target/rolling2/` от корня проекта. При запуске jar-a, логи будут в `target/rolling2/` от **текущего** каталога

Comment: @RomanKonoval в том-то и дело, что в текущем каталоге ничего не создается. Кстати, эту строчку я уже убрал и все равно ничего(

Comment: @RomanKonoval открыл jar-файл zip-ом - в корне архива **log4j2.properties** присутствует

Comment: Я таки нашел то место, где создается лог файл. Как оказалось файл создается в каталоге текущего пользователя по пути C:\Users\CurrentUser\ Как так получается не понятно

Comment: как вы запускаете приложение?

Comment: @RomanKonoval спасибо за наводку! Я запускал приложение из командной строки под текущим пользователем и поэтому логи писались в каталог пользователя. Вопрос закрыт)

Comment: Я запускал приложение из командной строки под текущим пользователем и поэтому логи писались в каталог пользователя.